# Format time fetched by breeze.js from a time column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, time, knockout.js, breeze

A time column in sql server table contains a value "10:50:00". When I run a breeze query to fetch data from the table, I find that breeze brings the time value as "PT10H50M". Not sure if  PT is for "Pacific Time". How can breeze just return me the value as stored in the table so that I can format the time using moment ?

I am using Timespan datatype for the property in my model class.

Answer (score 1):

'Time' objects are being returned to the Breeze client using an [ISO8601 Duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  Moment.js has a section on how to handle these here: [Moment Duration handling](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer times and ISO8601 Durations can be difficult to work with in javascript because you have to convert to edit, and then convert back to store.  (I have not found any timepicker controls that work with ISO8601 durations directly)

Momentjs supports durations, but does not yet support these conversions.

Here is are two github libraries that enhance momentjs to do this conversion process.

[moment.isoduration](https://github.com/dordille/moment-isoduration/blob/master/moment.isoduration.js)

[moment.interval](https://github.com/luisfarzati/moment-interval)